Create and Load SQL Server Temp Table (#Table or ##Table) from Databricks
Requirements:
We have a scenario where we need to load millions of records from Databricks into a SQL Server table with no keys/indexes. We are facing an issue in that we are unable to handle issues with failures. Deleting partially loaded data is not possible since the table is extremely huge and deletion takes a really long time. Spark seems to commit every few records even if AutoCommit is set to False besides other weird issues. So basically we want an All-In or nothing...
Approach:
To resolve the issue, we are trying to create a temp table in SQL Server from Databricks, load the dataframe into it. Later we will load from that temp table into the actual target table using a transaction that will commit if successful or rollback if not. We are trying to use pyodbc for this.
Issue:

We are unable to create the temp table using pyspark code.
Within the same notebook, if we use pyodbc in cell 1 to create the temp table, will it be available for load using the pyspark code in cell 2 ? If cursor and connection is closed in cell 1, will the temp table still be available in cell 2 ?

2.1. cell 1 - pyodbc code - just small part - conn, cursor creation assumed
drop_create_temp_table_query = """
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempTable;
SELECT <COL_LIST> INTO #TempTable FROM <SQL SERVER TABLE>;
"""
cursor.execute(drop_create_temp_table_query)

# Commit the transaction
conn.commit()

# Close the connection
cursor.close()
conn.close()

2.2. Cell 2 - Load from DF to Temp Table
df.write.format("jdbc").options(**jdbc_options).option("dbtable","##TempTable").save()

2.3. Cell 3 - pyodbc code
qry = """BEGIN TRANSACTION
Load from temp table to actual table
COMMIT TRANSACTION

CATCH
Rollback if there is an error.
"""


Assuming this option works, how should we mention the table name in spark JDBC write ? Just ##TempTable or tempdb..##TempTable ?


DB belongs to a different team, hence unable to request for a physical table, and the need for the temp table. Question is what is the scope of the session, is it just the duration of Cell 1 or the entire notebook ? is there any way we can extend the life of the temp table till the notebook ends its execution ?

@testing-for-ya Thank you for your response, but to create a table in tempdb I would need create table permissions which I do no have. I would get a CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'tempdb'. error. The reason I was exploring #table and ##table was with the hope that maybe the global temp table maybe available by the time I tried accessing it in the pyspark code in cell 2...

Luckily you work in the same company, so talk to the other team and come up with a solution. A staging table is the common way of solving imports. Although, if the other table has no indexes, I don't have much hope for your whole setup. If you didn't use spark, but raw sql, you should be able to create a table and then use it as target, as long as you keep same session, not sure why spark doesnt

@siggemannen yes, that is the end game - just want to exhaust all my options before raising the flag...since that route would take a really long time...

If you use #TempTable (local temp table), it will only be available in the session that created it.
Once you close the connection (conn.close()), the table will no longer be available.
I have tried the below approach:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import datetime
jdbcHostname = "slservdilip.database.windows.net"
jdbcPort = 1433
jdbcDatabase = "db02"
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};database={jdbcDatabase}"
connectionProperties = {
    "user": "admin02",
    "password": "Welcome@1"
}
data1 = [(4, "Alice Smith", 35),
         (5, "Michael Johnson", 45),
         (6, "Emily Davis", 28)]
columns1 = ["id", "name", "age"]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, columns1)
data2 = [("Alice Smith", "alice@example.com"),
         ("Michael Johnson", "michael@example.com"),
         ("Emily Davis", "emily@example.com")]
columns2 = ["name", "email"]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, columns2)
data3 = [("alice@example.com", "San Francisco"),
         ("michael@example.com", "Seattle"),
         ("emily@example.com", "Boston")]
columns3 = ["email", "city"]
df3 = spark.createDataFrame(data3, columns3)
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("contacts")
df3.createOrReplaceTempView("locations")
def exportToSql(spark, dbtable, sqltable):
    try:
        print(f"{dbtable}, start time: {datetime.datetime.now()}")
        df = spark.table(dbtable)
        df.write \
            .format("jdbc") \
            .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
            .option("dbtable", sqltable) \
            .options(**connectionProperties) \
            .mode("overwrite") \
            .save()
        print(f"{dbtable}, export completed: {datetime.datetime.now()}")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
exportToSql(spark, 'people', 'dbtable1')
exportToSql(spark, 'contacts', 'dbtable2')
exportToSql(spark, 'locations', 'dbtable3')

In the above code I am creating temporary SQL views for these DataFrames
Defining a function (exportToSql) to write the views to corresponding SQL Server tables using JDBC.
Finally,the data from Spark is exported into three SQL Server tables (dbtable1, dbtable2, dbtable3).
Results:


thank you...the issue has not been with reading from databricks views to SQL Server table...as you said the temp table is getting removed once I hit conn.close. Issue is with partial loads to a huge sql server table with no keys/indexes - (in billions) where restartability becomes an issue - hence if I can load to a temp table - I will be able to control the load to the huge table and manage the COMMIT through pyodbc...

i mean, that part I have tested, it works, challenge is making the temp table remain from its creation in the pyodbc part (temp table creation) to the spark load (df to temp table) to the pyodbc part (insert from temp to actual table) - or alternatively a reliable to commit only if a bunch of processes (2 df to sql server inserts + 2 df to sql server updates) are successful or else rollback...
